# NVIC System Reset fails

Tags: stm32, interrupt, reset, freertos, stm32f7

I’m using STM32f767zi with FreeRTOS kernel. I have two task:

1- one is triggered by a task notification from an interrupt every 100ms and receives some data through TCP.

2- the other task is handling some requests from user.

Now, if task-2 request for a system reset using `NVIC_SystemReset` API, system reset fails and every things hangs. When I run debugger, it seems it hangs in `vPortRaiseBASEPRI`. In disassembly, that is a few lines after `vTaskNotifyFromISR` which is the notification function I used for task-1.

When I remove that task notification and use just a flag in the interrupt, the system reset works fine. However, I think this way consumes the processor cycles and will not be efficient.

I tried to disable interrupts `portDISABLE_INTERRUPT`, tasks `vTaskSuspendAll` or enter critical `taskENTER_CRITICAL` but nothing work.

I did a way around method by requesting to `portDISABLE_INTERRUPT` in an independent request (so that any pended interrupt or “notification” can finish), then sending system reset in another request. This one works, however, it is not safe because the user can (by mistake) do the system reset before disabling interrupts.

Note that when I do hardware reset (push button on board) it works fine?!

So, any idea how to solve this problem? how to reset the board by software without that issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved by simply adding some delay after disabling task-1 interrupt:

```
NVIC_DisableIRQ(IRQn);
vTaskDelay(xTicksToDelay);
NVIC_SystemReset();
```

I still don't know if this solved the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

it is not system reset as system reset works **always**.

From the symptoms - you have wrong interrupt priorities set. All the used ones have to be lower the sysPENDV interrupt. Otherwise the context switch cannot happen (as this interrupt will not pre-empt the current one) and the result is as you observe.
https://www.freertos.org/RTOS-Cortex-M3-M4.html

[image]

> I tried to disable interrupts portDISABLE_INTERRUPT, tasks
> vTaskSuspendAll or enter critical taskENTER_CRITICAL but nothing work.

Do not disable interrupt if you do not understand how the RTOS works and what are consequences of it.

Comment: PendSV is set by FreeRTOS to be the lowest interrupt priority. You don't want the context switch to happen inside ISR. @P__J__

Comment: ISR will be pre-empted by the context switch only when you want it (by using `...fromISR`) functions. If your prioritiess are opposite you **must not** use `...fromISR` functions

Comment: I put PendSV 0 priority(highest), doesn't work. @ P__J__

Comment: It does not work like this. Read freeRTOS documentation. Blindly changing the priorities will not work.

Comment: You said that "blindly" in your answer.